# Probability exercise with apples

Tags: probability

> We have a tree with 100 apples. There are 10 red apples and the rest
>   are green. Lisa is picking apples at random. When she pick the **3rd red**
>   apple she stop. What is the probability that Lisa has exactly 7 green
>   apples (in addition to the 3 red apples she picked)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:  she has to pick 2 red and 7 green, then pick a red. How many ways are there to do that?  How many ways to pick 10 apples?

Added:  to pick an unordered 2 red and 7 green, you need to choose 2 out of 10 red and choose 7 of 90 green. Divide this by an unordered choice of 9 of 100

Comment: i thought about it too but when she pick a red apple the probability of picking red apple next time will changed, same with green

Comment: But you can just look at the chance that the first nine are what you want.  You pick 9 out of the 100 and ask the chance they have the correct color distribution.

Comment: pick 2 red: (10/100)*(9/99)* pick 7 green:(90/98)*(89/97)....*(84/92)

sorting 9 apples in a line : 9!
choosing the last red apple: (8/91)
now what?

Comment: We are counting unordered.  Pick two red is ${10 \choose 2}$ and seven green is ${90 \choose 7}$ ways, so the chance of that is $\frac{{10 \choose 2}{90\choose 7}}{{100 \choose 9}}\approx 0.1767$ Then the chance of a red (from what is left) is $\frac 8{91}$